# dual monitor while gaming

Tags: linux, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro with XFCE and I've got dual monitors...
I want to make the mouse cursor stuck on a single monitor while gaming or, while the game app is focused. Maybe there is a solution for it or the other way is to disable the second monitor while gaming and after I close the game it will turn on automatically. I know I can use `xrandr --off`, which I'm doing manually but looking for better solution...

Comment: There is a bit hacky solution via shellscript: https://pastebin.com/SuQrcSx0